# How to share internet from Debian to Router which is connected through mobile USB-Tethering?

Tags: debian, networking, ethernet, internet, plasma5

I'm using `Debian` with `Plasma`. I'm getting internet through `USB-tethering` from a Android device.
I want to share the Internet with Router connected through Ethernet. I did this in windows, but new to Linux. Please help me to solve.

[image]

This is how it looks like in GUI.

I'm ready to solve this in any manner, either using GUI or CLI. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Select your wired connection (not the mobile one, not sure if the "Modem" connection is your wired connection, if not, you'll need to create a new "Wired Ethernet" connection using the plus button) and on the **IPv4 tab** change **Method** to **Shared to other computers**.

I've never tried this with USB tethering, but it works fine with WiFi and the second device needs no special configuration.

[image]